Alternative text for chess images
When posting a picture of a chess board, in a blog post or a website, what should the alt text be?
The text that will be shown in case the image was not shown.
example, html img tag <img src"chessimg.png" alt="" />
I am assuming an explanation of the chess position with the pieces' coordinates?

The first thing that comes to mind is a PGN or FEN of the game. This would be a good alt text to show if the page doesn't load, but I don't know how useful it would be to someone using a screen reader.

@MrinalJain if FEN is a good choice, then i would prefer to stick to it because it is an official standard of writing chess position, however, i am not sure it is the best choice, the pieces of white and black are written with the same character, only difference is capitalization, so maybe there should be a standard for alt text for chess images.
